# Jqplot theme disappears the x axis labels

Tags: jqplot

When using a theme in `jqPlot` the x axis labels are disappeared. The colors are also added to the series and y axis tick label font size can also be set. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to sort this one out? Please share the code with solution, if you did solve it. Otherwise please share the code showing the problem.

Comment: No I didn't but that requirement was drawn away, Thanks for asking..Boro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue. When I switch theme (or even switch back to default) if I'm using

```
      renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
```

the x-axis texts are no longer drawn.

if I use

```
    $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
```

however they are drawn.

I've even tried specifying the renderer as part of the theme but this seems to be ignored (probably intentionally)

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on this issue right now (jqPlot v. 1.0.8) and I think I found the source of the problem. When going through the redraw process called at the end of ThemEngine activateTheme() function, in CategoryAxisRenderer's createTicks() the 'showLabel' property is set by default to false and fails to switch to true for ticks with labels.

**Fast fix that worked for me:** in plugin: *jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.js*

comment

```
t.showLabel = false; @line 149
```

and uncomment

```
t.showLabel = true; @line 155
```

After those changes everything works as intended both with default and user created theme. I have to stress out again that this is just a quick fix and not the final solution which I'll post here asap.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to just set the option.seriesColors directly which worked for me. This means the theme only exists as something in my helper functions that create graphs but it is ok for me.